# What new technologies should I learn if I'm working with ASP MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been developing web applications using ASP MVC3 for more than a year and I am wondering which good technologies/frameworks would be good to take a look at in order to improve as a .NET Web Developer.

I've already been using jQuery and jQuery UI and have investigated a little bit about knockout.js. I'd be more interested in things that integrate well with other .NET technologies (specially ASP MVC).

Answer (score 3):

- SquishIt (for compression of CSS and JS),
- ActionMailer.Net (for emails),
- HTML5 Boilerplate (in master pages),
- MSpec (for Unit Tests),
- Fluent NHibernate (for Database comms - Entity Framework alternative),
- Ninject (for dependency injection).
- Templify is also good when you want to package up a template you've created, it'll save you time when starting new projects...

Answer (score 2):

I would say Entity Framework Code First and WCF are essential these days.  On top of this JQuery, which you mentioned is also very useful.

But aside from these you should also become familiar with, if you are not already, unit testing frameworks like NUnit and mocking frameworks like MoQ.

If you want to really forge ahead then learning TDD and BDD techniques is a plus as well as using the Agile methodology.

You should also get a good grip of SOLID principles.  There is plenty of information about this on the internet.  This will improve the quality of your code.

For improving your efficiency in writing code I would recommend ReSharper.

There are so many other things you can use to help you write better code or improve your efficiency, like using a tool such as StyleCop.

I'm not saying that all these things are great and everything else is not.  I'm just saying that these are some of the things you can use in your arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

This is cool for your style sheets http://lesscss.org/